# pd.read_sql unicode types causing problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm formatting some data I'm pulling from a database using sqlalchemy, pyodbc, and pandas read_sql, which I get back as a dataframe `df`.

I want to apply a formatting of the data in each 'cell' of the dataframe, row by row and excluding the first two columns using this:

```
df.iloc[6, 2:] = (df.iloc[6, 2:]*100).map('{:,.2f}%'.format)
```

I apply a similar formatting for several other rows in the dataframe. This used to work great when I was reading my data from a `csv` file, but now reading from the database causes a ValueError on that line that reads:

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'unicode'
```

I tried some other casting attemps such as:  `df.iloc[6, 2:] = (float(df.iloc[6, 2:].encode())*100).map('{:,.2f}%'.format)`  But this causes some additional errors.

I'm pretty sure the error is being caused by the unicode type of the results. How should I format my dataframe or modify my read_sql to not have unicode strings?  I'm using python 2.7 by the way.

The `dtype` for each column is `object`.

Comment: can you provide an output of: `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: It says the dtype for each column is 'object'.  Series([], Name: 6, dtype: object)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do string formatting for a `float`, but you're actually passing it a string.

To illustrate the source of your error, consider the following:

```
'{:,.2f}%'.format(u'1')
```

which raises the same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-fb59302ab6b7> in <module>()
----> 1 '{:,.2f}%'.format(u'1')

ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'unicode'
```

To solve this, cast your string (dtype = `object`) columns to float, e.g.

```
# get columns to cast to float
vals = df.select_dtypes(['object']).astype(float)
cols = vals.columns

# and replace them
df[cols] = vals
```

Alternatively, you could put some logic in your mapper, e.g.

```
def safe_float_formatter(value):
    try:
        return '{:,.2f}%'.format(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

df.map(safe_float_formatter)
```

Comment: Thanks Kris, one caveat though is that some of the values are actually strings, written as 'N/A'.   Which yielded this error:  ValueError: could not convert string to float: N/A

Comment: So my question is whether there's a way to skip or ignore any value that would cause an error in the type conversion

Comment: I see.. I updated the answer (starting from "Alternatively ...")